# How to generate random slug in Postgres based on existing JS code?

Tags: postgresql

I have access to a Javascript function I'm using to randomly generate slugs upon creation of an item from the client side, which looks like this:

```js
export function uuid() {
  return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
    var r = (Math.random() * 16) | 0,
      v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3) | 0x8
    return v.toString(16)
  })
}
```

What I'd rather do though is to have that slug automatically generated in my Postgres database upon creation of an item.

What's a Postgres function I can write that would achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up handling it:

```postgresql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.generate_slug()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    NEW.slug := gen_random_uuid();
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$
```

Because I'm using SupabaseJS, I don't have access to the raw trigger, but essentially I'm executing this function on INSERT. Works like a charm!